# json deserialized property name to default object name

Tags: c#, json, .net

I have a deserialized object property that taken from a web service. I resemble the property name based on the json object. For example:

User.cs

```
public class UserProfileDTO
    {

        [JsonProperty("user_ext_fullname")]
        public string Fullname { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("user_ext_dateofbirth")]
        public string DateOfBirth { get; set; } 
    }
```

Controller

```
    userdto = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileDTO>(result);
    return userdto;
```

The issue is that I want to refer the naming object to be "Fullname" not "ext_user_fullname" on the later output. Is there any way to override the jsonproperty name to my default object name?

Current result

```
 "user_ext_fullname": "emir",
"user_ext_dateofbirth": null,
```

expected result

```
"fullname": "emir",
"dateOfBirth": null,
```

Comment: Can you post json that you have now and json you would like to have pls?

Comment: Hi Serge, I just edited the post

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
var json= "{ \"user_ext_fullname\":\"name\",\"user_ext_dateofbirth\":\"DOB\"}";
    
var userProfileDto=JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<UserProfileDTO>(json);
    
json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(userProfileDto, new JsonSerializerSettings
    {
        ContractResolver = new CamelCasePropertyNamesContractResolver()
    });
```

output

```
{"fullname":"name","dateOfBirth":"DOB"}
```

class

```
public class UserProfileDTO
{
    public string Fullname { get; set; }
    public string DateOfBirth { get; set; }
    
    public UserProfileDTO (string user_ext_fullname, string user_ext_dateofbirth)
    {
        Fullname=user_ext_fullname;
        DateOfBirth=user_ext_dateofbirth;
    }
}
```

Comment: The object has not changed on me. And I actually wanted to change the json to .net type, that is why I use deserializedobject

Comment: @emirryhn What means "has not changed on me"? And you can not see  that I  am using deserializedobject too?